# Transfer progress (Command and Conquer 95)

Tags: command-and-conquer

I'm playing Command and Conquer (1995) on my desktop computer with Windows 7 (64 bit).
Since I'm going to replace my HDD with a new SSD, I wonder how can I keep and transfer my progress when I installed C&C 95 on my new SSD.

Answer (score 7):

The game keeps its savegames in the game folder. Look for all the files called "savegame.???", with the extension being a number from 000 to 999.

There are also savegame packs available on the website of [the unofficial 1.06 patch project](http://nyerguds.arsaneus-design.com/cnc95upd/cc95p106/), though do keep in mind those were saved in higher resolution, and might not work well on the unpatched original. Though, simply applying the patch obviously solves that.

Side note: "C&C 95" is *not* "Command & Conquer (1995)"; it is "Command & Conquer, *Windows '95 Edition*". The C&C *from* 1995 is a DOS game. The Windows port, C&C95 (also known as "C&C Gold"), was in fact released in 1997. This distinction is especially important here, since the savegames of these two versions are not compatible.